# How to login in JupyterHub

Tags: jupyterhub

So, I got my user and passwd to access a jupyterHub from a science group.  As I just know jupyter notebook and I only use it locally, I have no clue about how to access JupyterHub.

Do I need any other infos besides user and passwd  to access it? How/Where can I log in?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need the URL of the JupyterHub server and the port number (default port is 8000).

For example: https://jupyterhub-fqdn:8000

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.